# Autofac in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, autofac, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to learn how to use autofac in MVC and not having a great deal of luck.

I installed Autofac.mvc5 from Nuget version 4.01
and Autofac v4.6.1

I have the following controller:

```
    [Authorize]
public class NotificationsController : ApiController
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public NotificationsController(IMapper notificationMapper)
    {
        _context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        _mapper = notificationMapper;
    }

    public IEnumerable<NotificationDto>GetNewNotifications()
    {
        var userId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

        var notifications = _context.UserNotifications
                            .Where(un => un.UserId==userId)
                            .Select(un=>un.Notification)
                            .Include(n=>n.Gig.Artist).ToList();




        return notifications.Select(notification => _mapper.Map<NotificationDto>(notification)).ToList();


    }
}
```

My Global.Asax is:

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        ConfigureAutofac();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);



    }

    private void ConfigureAutofac()
    {
        var autoMapperConfig = new MapperConfiguration(c =>
        {
            c.AddProfile(new NotificationProfile());
        });

        var mapper = autoMapperConfig.CreateMapper();

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterInstance(mapper);

        builder.Register(x => new NotificationsController(x.Resolve<IMapper>()));

        var container = builder.Build();
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new AutofacDependencyResolver(container));
    }
}
```

What I'm finding is that when I call this using postman I get an error saying I need a parameterless consturctor, but then if I put in the constructor _mapper is null.

Could someone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your controller derives from `ApiController`, so you are not using MVC, you are using WebApi (I assume WebApi2). So, you should use either `Controller` and MVC, or install Autofac.WebApi2 NuGet package to handle WebApi2.

Also, instead of registering all your controllers manually, you could use `RegisterControllers()` for MVC or `RegisterApiControllers()` for WebApi to have all your controllers registered at once. Especially, when your `NotificationController` does not use any fancy injection to require more custom registration.

The documentation describes very well, how you should use Autofac with [MVC](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/mvc.html) or [WebApi](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/integration/webapi.html), you should start there.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'll give it a go.